# Is possible to get very narrow beamwidth antenna?

Tags: arduino, power, wireless, antenna, gain

Is possible to make  60 dBi sector or patch antenna by make its beam width 0.17°/0.17° only ?

how to calculate ideal dimensions against frequency at this range of beam width ?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "[aperture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture)". You can make narrow-beamwidth antennas, but the aperture needs to be very large with respect to the wavelength in question.

Comment: As you perhaps know - there are antenna dishes with 100m diameter (and more).

Comment: I talking about sectors not dishes

Comment: For a dish, you could use this calculator : http://www.satsig.net/pointing/antenna-beamwidth-calculator.htm

Comment: You haven't said what frequency you want to use, but at 2.4GHz a dish antenna does what you want, and it's only 50m diameter. Making it accurate enough (within say 0.1 wavelength at 2.4GHz) may be an interesting challenge.

Comment: sorry , I  talking about 40 & 20 meters bands .

Comment: wow ... just wow. As far as I can tell your antenna will be about the size of Manhattan and a serious hazard to aviation.

Comment: A bit of background reading is recommended. This is like asking if you can make a car that goes at 40,000 mph, and how to calculate the size of the engine.

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer is that a \$60\$ dBi gain antenna is very large both physically and electrically.  I would not expect that one could build one using reasonable technology.

Gain can be estimated based on the effective aperture surface area.

$$\text{gain (in dBi)} = 10 \log \left( 4 \pi \times \frac{\text{area}}{\text{wavelength}^2} \right)$$